# Дочерний объект опускает родителя! Как так?

Tags: css

Есть код:

```html
<body bgcolor="#ffffff" text="#2275c2" link="#2275c2" vlink="#bf5a5a" style="margin:0px;">
  <div style="background-color:#e5f3ff; height:100%; width:100%; box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 20px 0px #5cb1ff; position:relative;">
    <center>
      <span style="font: bold 32px 'Trebuchet MS'; color:#5cb1ff; text-shadow: 1px 1px 0px #000000; position:relative; display:block; margin-top:20%;">тел. 8 (322) 223-322-23</span>
    </center>
  </div>
</body>
```

(*тут результат работы кода выглядит совсем не так, как его обрабатывает нормальный браузер. Лучше смотреть в это хэтэмээльке)
Вопрос:
Как так получается, что дочерний объект [`span`] опускает родительский [`div`] [`margin'ом`]?

Comment: то есть вы не можете воспроизвести проблему?

Comment: @I_CaR, span не опускает родительский, он опускает свойство bodyб так как для него свое приоритетнее. Это раз. А два- если б вы указали свойство в спан инхерит, то не опускал бы. А так у него нету правила подчиняться родителю.

Comment: Если я не ошибаюсь - вам про схлопывание марджинов надо прочесть http://www.xiper.net/learn/css/box-model/margin-collapsing.html .....и вообще про схлопывание  http://htmlbook.ru/samlayout/blochnaya-verstka/skhlopyvayushchiesya-otstupy

Comment: @Niklex "А так у него нету правила подчиняться родителю" - По принципу рекурсии, разве матрёшка в матрёшке не является дочерним объектом? Или тогда какой смысл заключения объектов в другие объекты?

Answer (score 1):

1. Используй `<!doctype html>`.
2. Погугли margin collapse.
3. Ещё пара фиксов. См. сниппет.
4. Margin в процентах считается не так как ты думаешь.

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

div {
  border: 1px solid transparent;
}
```

```html
<body bgcolor="#ffffff" text="#2275c2" link="#2275c2" vlink="#bf5a5a" style="margin:0px;">
  <div style="background-color:#e5f3ff; height:100%; width:100%; box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 20px 0px #5cb1ff; position:relative;">
    <center>
      <span style="font: bold 32px 'Trebuchet MS'; color:#5cb1ff; text-shadow: 1px 1px 0px #000000; position:relative; display:block; margin-top:20%;">тел. 8 (322) 223-322-23</span>
    </center>
  </div>
</body>
```